# Postgres order by in wrong order

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Postgres order by get wrong result:

```
postgres=# SELECT (url) FROM posts_post ORDER BY url;
                                               url
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 http://nautil.us/issue/70/variables/aging-is-a-communication-breakdown
 https://github.com/felixse/FluentTerminal
 http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160408-the-ancient-peruvian-mystery-solved-from-space
 http://www.graffathon.fi/2016/presentations/additive_slides.pdf
(4 rows)
```

As you can see, there is a problem with "http://nautil.us/issue/70/variables/aging-is-a-communication-breakdown". It doesn't sort correctly.

I saved the parsed result in Postgres using Python and psycopg2, and come to point, where I can't test sorting, cause Postgres return order by with errors.

UPD: REPRODUCE:

```
CREATE TABLE test_post ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "title" text NOT NULL, "url" text NOT NULL, "created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test_post (title, url, created) VALUES ('Aging Is', 'http://nautil.us/issue/70/variables/aging-is-a-communication-breakdown', NOW()) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO test_post (title, url, created) VALUES ('Untrusted – a user', 'https://github.com/felixse/FluentTerminal', NOW()) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO test_post (title, url, created) VALUES ('Artyping (1939)', 'http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160408-the-ancient-peruvian-mystery-solved-from-space', NOW()) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO test_post (title, url, created) VALUES (' Applying the Universal', 'http://www.graffathon.fi/2016/presentations/additive_slides.pdf', NOW()) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

SELECT (url) FROM test_post ORDER BY url;
```

PostgreSQL 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u
1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

Comment: `":"` is less than `"s"` so it sorts correctly (http: should be before all https:).

Comment: @thebjorn Initially I thought that as well, but there are two lines beginning with "http" at the bottom.

Comment: @404 then those are the lines that are not sorted correctly (I'm assuming due to a zero-width-space character or similar). The question should be edited so it isn't necessary to scroll to find the problematic lines.

Comment: Edit your question, and paste `create table`, `insert`, and `select` statements that reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' thank you for your interest, I added statements to reproduce my problem.

Comment: Tag the Postgres version. Show the results with your reproducing limited set (so 4 instead of 33 rows). Anyway, works for me, Postgres 11.1.

Comment: @pirho added version and limited to 4 rows.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce it on my 11.2 on Windows, but the 11.1 version on dbfiddle.uk seems to have that problem as well: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=73b7ea32e47c94802ff9ac1799b99113 which is also using Debian. I wonder if that is some problem with the glibc or the collations

Comment: There is no problem with the ordering: Some collations ignores characters that are not letters or digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're using UTF8 encoding, specifying the collation instead of accepting the default should fix your immediate problem. Whether this is the *right* thing to do is application-dependent.

There are several different ways to specify the collation. You can specify it when the database cluster is initialized, when the database is created, when you run a query, etc. See [Collation support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/collation.html) in the docs for much more detail.

```
CREATE TABLE test_post (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    "title" text NOT NULL, 
    "url" text collate ucs_basic NOT NULL, 
    "created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_post (title, url, created) VALUES 
('Aging Is', 'http://nautil.us/issue/70/variables/aging-is-a-communication-breakdown', NOW()) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT INTO test_post (title, url, created) VALUES 
('Untrusted – a user', 'https://github.com/felixse/FluentTerminal', NOW()) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT INTO test_post (title, url, created) VALUES 
('Artyping (1939)', 'http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160408-the-ancient-peruvian-mystery-solved-from-space', NOW()) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT INTO test_post (title, url, created) VALUES 
(' Applying the Universal', 'http://www.graffathon.fi/2016/presentations/additive_slides.pdf', NOW()) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

SELECT (url) FROM test_post ORDER BY url;

http://nautil.us/issue/70/variables/aging-is-a-communication-breakdown
http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160408-the-ancient-peruvian-mystery-solved-from-space
http://www.graffathon.fi/2016/presentations/additive_slides.pdf
https://github.com/felixse/FluentTerminal
```